# Light bleeding through objects

Tags: three.js, lighting

I probably miss some basic concept, because I tried all light forms and materials, but I can't stop the light going through the plane or vice-versa.

I'd expect that light from the pointlight source is stopped by the object, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm such an idiot :)

Light source should be set to cast shadow. Plane should be set to cast shadow, box should be set to receive shadow.

Answer (score 1):

Shadows require four things:

1. To be enabled in the renderer (e.g. renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;)
2. To be enabled in the light (e.g. light.castShadow = true;)
3. To be accepted by the object (e.g. object.receiveShadow = true;)
4. To be generated by the object (e.g. object.castShadow = true;)